# Call method in static class using Reflection C#

Tags: c#

I have some static classes with different names and every class have method "Parse". How I can call methods of this classes using Reflection. 
I try to use Type.GetType("MyClass1") but this return null

```
namespace MyNameSpace{
public static class MyClass1
{
    public static MyObject Parse(string id)
    {
    .....
     return   new MyObject();
    }
}
public static class MyClass2
{
    public static MyObject Parse(string id)
    {
    .....
     return   new MyObject();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: [`Type.GetType("MyNameSpace.MyClass1, MyAssemblyName")`?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `typeof` to get the type descriptor. Use `GetMethod` to find the method. `Invoke` with null to invoke the `static` method.

```
typeof(MyClass1).GetMethod("Parse").Invoke(null, new object[] { "Parameter" });
```

If you have to find the type by string (which you didn't specify), you can do the following:

```
Type.GetType("MyNameSpace.MyClass1,Assembly");
```

Comment: Thanks, helped the second option